# Library Files not uploading to Bintray

Tags: android, maven, bintray

I'm trying to update an Android library on Bintray, But its not showing the new version of my library.

I updated my `VERSION_NAME` and `VERSION_CODE` in my library gradle.properties.

I updated my library version in my bintray.gradle file in my library.

My package name still remains the same.

Then I used the gradlew command.

```
./gradlew install

./gradlew bintrayUpload
```

As shown in https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

It shows me **BUILD SUCCESSFUL** for both commands but Never uploads my library on Bintray, neither do I see any files uploaded.

Any thing else I could be missing?

Comment: Please try instead of ./gradlew install, ./gradlew clean build install

Comment: Tried with no success. do you have the solution?

Comment: any solution to this problem yet? I'm facing the same issue for last few days.

Comment: Hi guys I had same issue last 2 days. I think the problem is a silent fail related to missing values e.g. key or user. Just a question do you previously uploaded files with same bintray gradle config or is your fist time. I mean I can post a full answer explaining how I fix it but no idea if is the same problem xD

Comment: @MiguelHincapieC  I had uploaded one library successfully. And now trying to upload second library and it shows build successful but no files uploaded on bintray.

Comment: @TechHelper after you execute `gradlew bintrayupload --info` you need to go back in terminal log and check if really the files were uploaded.

Comment: @TechHelper if you have questions about config files, take a look [at those](https://gist.github.com/miguelhincapie/7ca32d25561fc74b3d4c497758d597ed)

Comment: @MiguelHincapieC Thanks a lot for the help. I executed upload command with debug flag and got the exact error and fixed it quickly. Debug flag is the best way to understand the error.

Comment: I have a same issue, after careful checked, there is two user in my bintray so my uploaded libs goes to second user, and I continuous checking other users dashboard, please check whether or not it case for you.

Comment: I forgot to specify the publication, check if you did to: `setPublications("..."); publish = true`